# .NET MAUI Label Binding not updating in C# - Not MVVM

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui

Due to a bug with the latest CommunityToolkit.Maui.Mvvm package when used with Shell, I'm not using it. So I'm pushing ahead just writing everything in code (no Xaml). From what I can tell, this should work. I'm expecting the text of the last updated label to be updated, but it doesn't. Can anyone see why not?

```
namespace MyMauiApp;

public class DashboardPage : ContentPage
{
    private string _lastUpdated;
    private bool _loading;

    public DashboardPage()
    {
        LoadData = new AsyncCommand(SetData);

        RefreshView refreshView = new();
        refreshView.RefreshColor = ColourConstants.DesaturatedDark;
        refreshView.Bind(RefreshView.IsRefreshingProperty, nameof(_loading));
        refreshView.Bind(RefreshView.CommandProperty, nameof(LoadData));

        ScrollView scrollView = new();
        var dashgrid = new Grid
        {
            RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto) },                
            },
            ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto) },
            },
        }.CenterVertical();

        dashgrid.Add(new Label { Text = "Last Updated:" }, 0, 0);
        Label lastUpdated = new() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End };
        lastUpdated.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(LastUpdated));
        dashgrid.Add(lastUpdated, 1, 0);

        scrollView.Content = dashgrid;
        refreshView.Content = scrollView;
        Content = refreshView;
    }

    public string LastUpdated
    {
        get => _lastUpdated;
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LastUpdated));
            _lastUpdated = value;
        }
    }

    public AsyncCommand LoadData { get; }

    private async Task SetData()
    {
        try
        {
            LastUpdated = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm tt");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to set data");
        }
        finally
        {
            _loading = false;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _ = SetData();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I can see it 8o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code. First, you are not setting the `BindingContext` of any controls, so the bindings won't work even if they are set up correctly. The definition of your `Label` should look like this:

```csharp
Label lastUpdated = new() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End };
lastUpdated.BindingContext = this;
lastUpdated.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(LastUpdated));
```

Secondly, the setter for the `LastUpdated` property is wrong. First, you set the backing field value, *then* call `OnPropertyChanged` so the code knows that there was a change and the updated value can be propagated:

```csharp
public string LastUpdated
{
    get => _lastUpdated;
    set
    {
        _lastUpdated = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LastUpdated));
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: an alternative to setting BindingContext of each control, is to set BindingContext of any container of the control. Since there is no viewmodel, can set on the page itself: `this.BindingContext = this;`. This will be seen by all controls on the page.